# what does below java line indicates with final modifier assigned to list?

Tags: java

Please consider my question. final values cannot be changed in java.

```
private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

above list instantiation is of final. now i can add any elements.
after that can i assign list=null?

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should one use final?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154314/when-should-one-use-final)

Comment: Its more a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525642/java-final-arraylist then the link you posted @BeauGrantham.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the variable `list` is final.

Which means you can not assign something else to it again.

Once you are done assign a value (reference) to it as follows:

```
private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You can not do something as below again:

```
list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //this is invalid because you are trying to assign something else the variable list
```

> `list.add(new Integer(123));` is this code valid?

It's perfectly valid. You are just adding an object to the `ArrayList` that variable `list` is referencing.

The usage of `final` keyword is restricting the variable `list` not the `ArrayList` object that it's referencing.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` keyword in Java creates a new Object and returns its reference. Hence, in your code, the `list` variable stores the reference to the new list. Declaring it final means that the reference stored in `list` is final, and cannot be changed.

The actual list is still modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

The `final` keyword indicates that a variable can only be initialized once. It does **not** guarantee immutability of the object assigned to that variable. In other words, it says something about *what* a variable can refer to, but nothing about the *contents* of the referent.

Answer (score 1):

For your code and if you have this:

```
private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This is possible:

```
list.add(3);
```

This is not allowed:

```
list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```